# Create dynamic columns on NSTableView on reload

Tags: cocoa

I'm creating NSTableView and have problem with I change TableColumns. The header is appear black on terminate reload of data.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sqlite3_column_count(stmp); i++) {
    NSTableColumn *tableColumn = [NSTableColumn new];
    NSString *columnName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_name(stmp, i)];

    [tableColumn setIdentifier:columnName];
    NSCell *cell = [[NSCell alloc] initTextCell:columnName];
    [cell setFont:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[NSFont smallSystemFontSize]]];
    [tableColumn setHeaderCell:cell];
    [tableView addTableColumn:tableColumn];
}
```

How I do the reloading this header without lost style?

[image: NSTableView]

**EDIT 1**

```
for (int i = 0; i < sqlite3_column_count(stmp); i++) {
    NSTableColumn *tableColumn = [NSTableColumn new];
    NSString *columnName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_name(stmp, i)];

    [tableColumn setIdentifier:columnName];

    NSTextFieldCell *cell = [[NSTextFieldCell alloc] initTextCell:columnName];

    [cell setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
    [tableColumn setHeaderCell:cell];

    [self.tableView addTableColumn:tableColumn];
}
```

This code appear name of columns in header but not same initial style of header in `NSTableView`.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, are you saying your header row is OK at initialization, but after you reload the data it turns black?

Comment: I change `NSCell` to `NSTextFieldCell` and work without style in header. This enable change color text. But style lost on this process.

Comment: Could you maybe post more pictures and code?  I'm not sure if I'm seeing the whole picture here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm copy the header style to temporary variable on initialize `xib`

```
... 
[self copyColumnConfiguration:columnTemplate fromColumn:self.tableView.tableColumns[0]];
...

- (void)copyColumnConfiguration:(NSTableColumn*)dstColumn fromColumn: (NSTableColumn*)srcColumn
{
    id srcCell;
    id dstCell;

    srcCell = [srcColumn dataCell];
    dstCell = [dstColumn dataCell];
    [dstCell setAlignment:[srcCell alignment]];
    [dstCell setFormatter:[srcCell formatter]];

    srcCell = [srcColumn headerCell];
    dstCell = [dstColumn headerCell];
    [dstCell setAlignment:[srcCell alignment]];
}
```

And after create column copy to new column the style stored. 
For more information see http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2005/Nov/msg00949.html